# Custom actionbar and hide Logo and title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I customized my actionbar with a style to have my logo in the center.
I want to hide the logo and the title to the left of the actionbar and I do it with:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
```

It works, but my problem is I don't want hide the back button which is also to the left, and with `displayOptions` the back button is hidden even if I use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented the action bar, you should be able to set up home button using the following code.

This in the onCreate

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This as a separate method

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {

     case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intentHome = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
        intentHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentHome);
        return true;

     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Comment: The home button not appear with this code because I use `code`<item name="android:displayOptions"></item>`code` in style.xml for hide the logo and title. How it's possible to hide the logo and the title without hide the back button ?